# Qlik View and Sense

Tags: qlikview, qliksense

I am using Qlik sense and I need help with mapping or something related to mapping in 2 tables.

I have loaded 2 tables in to qlik sense. There is common columns which connects two tables. Now I need to copy 1 unique column from table 1 to table 2. 
I need to do this in Data Load Editor.
For more understanding I have provided [TABEL 2](https://i.stack.imgur.com/x2WCt.jpg) 
Sample below. 
 [image]

I DONT WANT TO JOIN TABLES 
I Don't know how to do it.
Can some one help me out.

Answer (score 2):

Update: `join` should not be used (see comments)

You can create `Mapping` table containing `postdata` and `Geodata` columns from `Table1` and use [ApplyMap](https://help.qlik.com/en-US/qlikview/12.1/Subsystems/Client/Content/Scripting/MappingFunctions/ApplyMap.htm) function on `postcode` field in `Table2`

```
Table1:
Load
  postcode,
  suburb,
  Geodata
From
  [folder path]
;

GeodataMapping:
Mapping
Load
  postcode,
  Geodata
Resident
  Table1
;

Table2:
Load
  postcode,
  suburb,
  Name,
  ApplyMap('GeodataMapping', postcode) as GeodataMaped
From
  [folder path]
;
```

Since `GeodataMapping` is a mapping table there is no need to be dropped. Mapping tables are not persistent

Comment: Thanks for your reply. It works fine.   But I dont want to join table.

Comment: in this case: its enough both tables to be linked only by `postcode` or you need the combination between `postcode` and `suburb`?

Comment: I tried with the code you provided it shows an error message with Field 'postcode' not found ! In Table 2 I have plenty of columns, Only Name is shown for example. @Stefan Stoichev

Comment: im using the screenshot as a guide and can see `postcode` column in `Table2` bu the error is stating that there is no such column there. Is it possible the `postcode` column in `Table2` to be called differently? QV/QS are case sensitive

Comment: Sorry I dint know its case sensitive. now I made the changes but now I am getting another error as -    ApplyMap error: map_id not found.

Comment: Make sure that the mapping table name is the same as in the 'ApplyMap' function (again case sensitive). In the example above the mapping table name is 'GeodataMapping'

Comment: Everything is same. I have attached the actual table 2 image in the question now. Kindly have a look at it please.